# Saving a Dictionary to a List Without the Dictionary Losing its Value

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
itemsInExistence = []
item = {}
item['name'] = input("What do you want the new item to be called? ")
item['stats'] = int(input("What is its stat? "))
item['rank'] = int(input("What is its base rank? "))
item['amount'] = int(input("How many of it are there? "))
for i in range(item['amount']):
    itemsInExistence.append(item)
```

later in the code...

```
gains = random.randint(1, 5)
if gains == 2:
  x = -1
  for i in itemsInExistence:
    x += 1
    print(x)
  gained_weapon = random.randint(0, x)
  print(gained_weapon)
  print("You gained the item", itemsInExistence[gained_weapon])
  itemMatrix.append(itemsInExistence[gained_weapon])
  print(itemMatrix)
  for i, item in enumerate(itemsInExistence):
    if gained_weapon == itemsInExistence[i]:
      del itemsInExistence[i]
      break
```

When item is appended to `itemMatrix`, it becomes one string. This is a problem, because I need to change the values of `item['rank']`, `item['stats']`, and `item['amount']` after those values become obsolete. And getting the values by `itemMatrix[num][-num]` doesn't work, it won't let me change it from a string to an integer.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This creates `item['amount']` aliases of `items` in `itemsInExistence`, which is unusual. Also, can you elaborate on "it becomes one string"--these all look like dicts full of ints to me due to your casts (I don't see any strings here). Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: You are not able to access `itemsInExistence[num][-num]` because `itemsInExistence` is a list and when you append the dictionary to list, it will convert to a string and store. If you need to access it again you have to convert to json format

Comment: How do I convert it to json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by item becomes one string. The code you have posted will result in `itemsInExistence` being a list containing a number of dictionaries equal to the value `item['amount']`.

For example:

```py
[
    {'name': 'Ball', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 1, 'amount': 2},
    {'name': 'Ball', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 1, 'amount': 2}
]
```

Accessing items inside of this list would be done by `itemsInExistence[0]['rank']`, changing the integer and string accordingly to access the desired data.

```py
itemsInExistence[1]['rank'] = 4
```

would then give you as list like this.

```py
[
    {'name': 'Ball', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 4, 'amount': 2},
    {'name': 'Ball', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 4, 'amount': 2}
]
```

**Update**

To access the data inside `itemMatrix` it would be the same as above with

```py
itemMatrix[-1]['rank'] = 10
# -1 accesses the last item in the list
```

So if you had something like this

```py
if gains == 2:
    x = len(itemsInExistence) -1
    gained_weapon = random.randint(0, x)
    
    print("You gained the item", itemsInExistence[gained_weapon])
    
    itemMatrix.append(itemsInExistence[gained_weapon])
    
    print(itemMatrix)
    
    itemMatrix[-1]['rank'] = 10
    
    print(itemMatrix)
```

You would get the following

```
What do you want the new item to be called? a
What is its stat? 1
What is its base rank? 2
How many of it are there? 3
You gained the item {'name': 'a', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 2, 'amount': 3}
[{'name': 'a', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 2, 'amount': 3}]
[{'name': 'a', 'stats': 1, 'rank': 10, 'amount': 3}]
```

Comment: This helped for itemsInExistence, but not for the new code.

Comment: OK, can you update the post further as more code seems missing. I say this because `x` would not be defined unless `gains` equals `2`, and `itemMatrix` is also undefined. Can you add in their default values for clarity please?

Comment: x is only defined if gains == 2, as for itemMatrix, it starts off at [ ], and is only added to when gains == 2. (there is also a .txt file that stores whatever is added to itemMatrix, so those would also be in there.)

Comment: If `x` is not defined unless `gains == 2` then you will get a `NameError` because x is used later `gained_weapon = random.randint(0, x)` unless the indentation is wrong?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm not sure where the string issue you mention is though? Do you have a traceback at all?

Comment: Are you using regular python? Line 11 of your code gives me Typeerror: 'str' object does not support item assignment.

Comment: I took the code and tested it without everything else, and it works just fine. Something in the rest of the program was messing it up.

Comment: I realize my problem is different than I thought. It turns out that how I save itemsInExistence is causing the errors. If I cannot fix that, I will post a new question. Thanks for your help!